# When new app instance launched, how to pass data to already running app instance

Tags: java, android, firebase, android-activity

My app architecture includes splash screen as launcher activity. Splash screen is destroyed after app is started. So, to prevent restarting app (because of launcher activity destroyed), I have added this in onCreate method for splash screen:

```
if (!isTaskRoot())
{
  finish();
  return;
}
```

So, new instance finishes itself if already running instance is there and running instance is shown. Good so far. 
However, new app instance not always starts from launcher. I have set Firebase Messaging to receive push messages from my server. Push message contains some additional data, it can be accesed this way:

```
String messageId = getIntent().getStringExtra("id_message");
```

when new app instance is launched after click on push message notification. In case when app is already running, I need to show it after push notification click (it works) and then process `message_id` with already running app instance (new instance should finish itself). But I don't know how to pass `message_id` to already running instance to be able to process it and show message details without restarting entire app.

Do you have any idea?

Answer (score 1):

You can use an intermediate Activity to choose which Activity to launch.

**First**, create the `LaunchActivity`:

```
public class LaunchActivity extends Activity {
  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.empty);

     BaseApp application = (BaseApp) this.getApplication();

    // determine where to go
    if(application.isHasGoToMain()) {
      Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
      intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
      finish();
      startActivity(intent);
    } else {
      Intent intent = new Intent(this, SplashScreenActivity.class);
      intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
      finish();
      startActivity(intent);
    }
  }
}
```

with the `empty` layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:visibility="gone">

</LinearLayout>
```

**Second**, create an Application to save if the main activity is already launched:

```
public class BaseApp extends Application {
  private boolean hasGoToMain = false;

  public boolean isHasGoToMain() {
    return hasGoToMain;
  }

  public void setHasGoToMain(boolean hasGoToMain) {
    this.hasGoToMain = hasGoToMain;
  }
}
```

you need to set the flag in the splash screen activity.

**Third**, set the `LaunchActivity` as the launcher in the `AndroidManifest.xml` and set it as hidden and `singleTask`:

```
<activity
    android:name=".LaunchActivity"
    android:screenOrientation="portrait"
    android:configChanges="orientation"
    android:launchMode="singleTask"
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoDisplay"
    android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden">
  <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
  </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

**Fourth**, you need to create your splash screen and main activity as `singleTask` too:

```
<activity
    android:name=".SplashScreenActivity"
    android:launchMode="singleTask"
    android:configChanges="screenSize|orientation|screenLayout">

</activity>

<activity
    android:name=".MainActivity"
    android:launchMode="singleTask"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppThemeMain.NoActionBar">
```

**Last**, you need to set the flag after splash activity is launched with:

```
public class SplashScreenActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
  ...
  @Override 
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ...

    BaseApp baseApp = (BaseApp) this.getApplication();
    baseApp.setHasGoToMain(true);
  }
}
```

Now you can send the intent and handle it within the `onNewIntent()` of the main activity.

Comment: Idea is interesting, definitely worth to try. My case is a bit more complicated, sequence is: Splash->Login (if not logged, stop on login to prompt password)->Main activity

Comment: That's the same case that I face. I'm handling the login in the login activity but the splash screen is not killed yet. After the login is success, the splash screen is notified and killed then starting the main activity from the splash screen.

Comment: In my case, SplashScreen finishes itself and LoginActivity launches. Otherwise, press back on LoginActivity will cause to show the splash again. LoginActivity must be on the top of stack

Comment: Ohhh.. I always close the whole app if user back press on login.

Comment: You mean override back press? Then kill the app. I feel it is not elegant way. Actually I can't find any guideline how to do all of this stuff right, really right and elegant way. Without any "dirty hacks"

Comment: Yes, the solution is not very elegant but it works in my case. But you can achieve the kill app process  by informing the splash screen to kill it self.

Comment: Well, we should not try to kill app on demand. This is generally bad practice. We need to let system to kill app gracefully when it should be killed. There is also no any way to make sure that app is really killed, even if you try to kill it.

Answer (score 0):

First add launch mode in that activity tag in manifest file like

```
<activity
android:name="your_activity_name"
android:launchMode="singleTop" />
```

When you click on notification and you are starting any activity

if your activity is not there then a fresh activity will start.
And if that activity is already opened then its onNewIntent(Intent intent) gets called and you will receive the data you sent in this intent parameter.

Comment: This is not a solution. Launcher activity is SplashActivity. When app is running, SplashActivity is already destroyed. So it will always start fresh SplashActivity, which will cause to app restart and run it from scratch, even if app is already running (after press Home button for example), `isTaskRoot()` is to avoid that and immediately shutdown unwanted second instance.

Comment: Instead of starting SplashActivity start the second activity which opened after splash from push

Comment: When app is not running in background, it should show splash. So, click action from fcm needs to point to splash activity. There is no other way than isTaskRoot to determine if app is already running or not.

Answer (score 0):

When the push is received in the app from firebase it will be handled by **MyFirebaseMessagingService**. Over there you need to create a pending intent ie,the activity that needs to be opened when the user taps on the notification.

```
Intent resultIntent = new Intent(context, ActivityToOpen.class);

    TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(context);
    stackBuilder.addNextIntentWithParentStack(resultIntent);
    PendingIntent resultPendingIntent = stackBuilder.getPendingIntent(0, 
  PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
```

Once the user clicks on the notification they will be diverted to the activity **ActivityToOpen**.In that activity you can put the following code

```
 Intent upIntent = 
 NavUtils.getParentActivityIntent(ActivityToOpenOnBackPress.this);
        if (NavUtils.shouldUpRecreateTask(CurrentActivityName.this, 
  upIntent)) 
       {

            TaskStackBuilder.create(CurrentActivityName.this)
                    .addNextIntentWithParentStack(upIntent)
                    .startActivities();
        } else {
            NavUtils.navigateUpTo(CurrentActivityName.this, upIntent);
        }
```

Put this code in the onBackPressed function or inside the toolbar navigation click listener.So when the user presses the back button an artificial stack is created and android handles the rest.

In the androidmanifest.xml assign a parent activity for each activity by adding the following code
    `android:parentActivityName=".ParentActivityName"`

Comment: The main problem is that my app is not receiving anything in `MyFirebaseMessagingService` if app is in background. Instead, notification click causes to launch new app instance (this is how notification payloads designed in Firebase). Then, I can get messageID from new instance via `getIntent().getStringExtra`. `onMessageReceived' will be called only if app is in foreground. And, because SplashActivity is destroyed... you know the rest.

Comment: When you are sending the fcm from the server i assume you have added a click action key in the payload which specifies the activity that will handle that payload when it is received on the phone?

Comment: Yes exactly. It points to splash. Otherwise, there will be lag and no splash shown in case when app is not already running - in this case, it should start as normal, show splash, then ask some actions from user and finally show processed message details

Comment: If your splash screen does not involve any animations then you can follwo this guide https://www.bignerdranch.com/blog/splash-screens-the-right-way/ which will basically apply a theme to your app, so then you won't have to redirect to the splashscreen activity, instead you can directly link to the requierd activity from the notification click and the splash screen will automatically show up since its the theme. In the case when you cannot use that solution i would suggest handling starting the required activity from the splash screen and calling finishAffinity() to clear the stack.

Comment: This is exactly the same solution as mine. However, you are wrong, SplashActivity is regular activity and it won't show automatically. Style is only used instead of SplashActivity layout, but still SplashActivity needs to be invoked, then finished. Splash activity i sandroid.intent.category.LAUNCHER and it needs to be directly invoked

Answer (score 0):

I had almost the same problem. My app starts from launcher or from intent. After adding a splashscreen activity the intent startet a second instance from the app if the app was in background.

I added android:launchMode="singleTask" to both activities in the manifest and now it works like before. Only one app instance at a time.

Doesn't make any sense to me, but as long as it works I don't care...

Comment: If your splash is destroyed (splash activity does not exist), it won't work unless your intent launches directly activity that already exists